# How can I find the broadcast address of a LAN in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I'm writing a script that relies on the ability to broadcast UDP datagrams to the current LAN and I was wondering whether there was a way to find the broadcast IP directly from Python.

I'm currently simply hard-coding it as follows, which might break down on a different subnet:

```
self.UDP_IP = '192.168.1.255'
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1)
sock.sendto('<Some message>', (self.UDP_IP, <Some port>))
```

Comment: There are ways to get the network mask, and from that deduce the broadcast address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to broadcast into your LAN, why use a directed broadcast? With 255.255.255.255 as target, your transmission will always become an Ethernet broadcast, which seems to fulfill what you want. But I probably misunderstand what you want.

Comment: You did not misunderstand, 255.255.255.255 does seem to work

Comment: Nice! The IPv6-equivalent would be a multicast like ff02::1, by the way.

Comment: I know this is old but I'm having an issue on my end. when I send a socket msg to 192.168.1.255, my other python server on a linux box can see the message but if i do 255.255.255.255, my linux box wont see it. anything I am missing?

Comment: Did you set the broadcast flag as socket option?